# Django local server stopped working

Tags: python, django, localhost

As far as I am aware, nothing in my configuration has changed except my location (network connection) and a minor update to OSX.

I can go back to known working commits in my git repository and still does not work, so I know it's not the project or project settings.

The server is 'running' on 0.0.0.0:8000 and I'm using django-hosts to map urls onto a custom host (blah.blah.org:8000, for example).

Going to the custom host gets me a webpage not available, and going to the 0.0.0.0:8000 actually pings the server, but doesn't do much else (nor should it, because of django-hosts).

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was something to do with the router configuration I was connected to. I was recommended to just add 0.0.0.0 to the hosts file intercepting my local site, which works fine. If anyone is out traveling around and has the same problem:

http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/